# How to make screen saver transparent?

Tags: windows, screen

Is it possible to make the Windows Screen Saver transparent?

When the screen saver is active we see what is going on but when we move the mouse the password is required to enter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the screen saver runs on another desktop.

Comment: Hans is referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx.  "Secure screensavers" are the ones that require a password, and they run on a separate desktop from your normal programs.

Comment: @aF.: I know it's been asked a long time ago. I'm curious though, have you been successful implementing a transparent screensaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the screensaver window is just that, a topmost window (which can display anything); just use the usual methods of making a transparent window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Comment: So, how can I access the screenc saver window?

Comment: Presumably you wrote the screen saver, so you should already have your own window handle.

Comment: I'll accept it. So I'll need to "make" the screen saver in order to control it. Got it!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tranpsarent Screen Lock](http://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.htm) It has a module called Transparent Screen Lock.SCR that can be launched as a screensaver.